Applying the Trapezoidal Method for Integration on Matrix in C
I have a 2x2 matrix, called "one_elect", which is a function of a variable "r" but I am a little confused as to how to apply the Trapezoidal Method for integrating onto this matrix. I am a decent beginner in C; essentially, I don't know how to loop this matrix for that particular variable. Please see the code below for a beginner trapezoidal integration code and the code I am working on.
My Code containing the function I want to use for the integration Method:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Z 1
#define BASISFUN 2
#define UPPER 100 // This is the Upper bound for the integral
#define LOWER 0   // This is the lower bound of the integral
#define SUBINT 50 // This is the number of subintervals for Integration

void makingmatrix(double a[][BASISFUN], double d[][BASISFUN], double alpha_coeff[BASISFUN], double d_coeff[BASISFUN]){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < BASISFUN; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BASISFUN; j++){
            a[i][j] = alpha_coeff[j];
            d[i][j] = d_coeff[j];
        }
    }

    printf("\nAlpha 2x2 Coefficient Matrix is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BASISFUN; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BASISFUN; j++){
            printf("%.4f\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

   printf("\nD 2x2 Coefficient Matrix is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BASISFUN; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BASISFUN; j++){
            printf("%.4f\t", d[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");    
    }
    printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
};

void one_ele(double a[][BASISFUN], double d[][BASISFUN], double r, double one_electron[][BASISFUN]){

    double i_step = (UPPER-LOWER)/SUBINT;

    for (int i = 0; i < BASISFUN; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < BASISFUN; j++){
                
                if (i != j){
                    one_electron[i][j] = (0.5) * (-2 * a[i][j] * r * exp(-a[i][j] * pow(r, 2))) * (-2 * a[j][i] * r * exp(-a[j][i] * pow(r, 2))) + (Z / r);
                } 
                
                else{
                    one_electron[i][i] = (0.5) * (-2 * a[i][i] * r * exp(-a[i][i] * pow(r, 2))) * (-2 * a[i][i] * r * exp(-a[i][i] * pow(r, 2))) + (Z / r);
                }
            }
    }
 printf("\nOne Electron Hamiltonian Elements are\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BASISFUN; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < BASISFUN; j++){
            printf("%.4f\t", one_electron[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main(){
    double A1 = 0.532149, A2 = 4.097728, D1 = 0.82559, D2 = 0.28317;
    double r;
    
    double alpha_coeff[BASISFUN] = {A1, A2};
    double d_coeff[BASISFUN] = {D1, D2};
    double a[BASISFUN][BASISFUN], d[BASISFUN][BASISFUN];
    
    makingmatrix(a, d, alpha_coeff, d_coeff);
    one_ele(a, d, r, one_electron);
    
    return 0;
}

Sample code for Trapezoidal Rule:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BASISFUN 2 
#define Z 1.0
#define UPPER 100 // This is the Upper bound for the integral
#define LOWER 0   // This is the lower bound of the integral
#define SUBINT 50 // This is the number of subintervals for Integration 

double f(double r) {
    // Define your function here
    return (0.5) * (-2 * a[i][j] * r * exp(-a[i][j] * pow(r, 2))) * (-2 * a[i][j] * r * exp(-a[i][j] * pow(r, 2))) + (Z / r);
}

int main() {
    double stepSize = (UPPER - LOWER) / SUBINT;
    double integral = f(a) + f(b);

    for (int i = 1; i < SUBINT; i++) {
        double r = a + i * stepSize;
        integral += 2 * f(r);
    }

    integral *= stepSize / 2.0;

    printf("Required value of integration is: %.3f\n", integral);
    return 0;
}



Trivia: the }; at the end of the first function in the first sample is redundant — tech nically, it is an empty declaration.  The } marks the end of the function; it does not need more punctuation.

Not trivia: the value of r passed to one_ele() is indeterminate; it is never initialized or assigned a value.

In one_ele(), you compute values: if (i != j) { one_electron[i][j] = (0.5) * (-2 * a[i][j] * r * exp(-a[i][j] * pow(r, 2))) * (-2 * a[j][i] * r * exp(-a[j][i] * pow(r, 2))) + (Z / r); } else { one_electron[i][i] = (0.5) * (-2 * a[i][i] * r * exp(-a[i][i] * pow(r, 2))) * (-2 * a[i][i] * r * exp(-a[i][i] * pow(r, 2))) + (Z / r); }.  You do not need the condition — AFAICS, the formulae in the two expressions work identically when i == j (which is easier to see in the question than a comment).  There is no need for two expressions — or there's a bug in the code because there's no difference.

How is the "integration over the matrix" supposed to work?  I can see how you might be able to step r over a range of values, changing the matrices and therefore the results.  But what is the output value that you are summing?  Is it the determinant of the matrix, or something else?

The one_elec is a matrix product containing both mixed "I,j" terms and pure "i,i" terms. Thus, the matrix product elements are as follows 0 assuming "h" represents the one_elect matrix: h_overall = {{hii, hij}, {hji, hjj}}

Hence the conditional statements; however, I dont know how to integrate over r when the values of r is dynamic - between the limit provided. I was thinking of having nested loops in the form of something like this: 'for(int i, i > BASISFUN, i++){ for (int j, j>BASISFUN, j++) {for (int r, r> 100, r+stepsize){ EVERYTHING ELSE'

@JonathanLeffler The determinates and off-diagonal terms play crucial roles in comparing to experimental results. The bounds of the limits are determined by fluctuating them until results comparable to the experimental ones are achieved. Another way of thinking of this is finding the most optimal value of r until the Gaussian functions - which the one_electron term is a function of - become constant.

I'm sorry — I'm lost and can't help.

@JonathanLeffler is right to point out that your test if (i !=j) is futile. A couple of other stylistic comments about excessive use of brackets and (0.5)*(-2*...) really makes me groan. Also don't use pow(r,2) it is less accurate and much slower than r*r. What function exactly is it that you want to integrate over? BTW Using the Trapezium rule is inexcusable these days - Simpson's method is only  marginally more complex and a lot more accurate.

@MartinBrown, I took into consideration Mrs. Leffler's suggestion regarding my current code on my local machine. I love and appreciate all the advice given to me, i.e., your comment about 'r*r' is something that I had really not thought of. Mathematically, the one_elect is a function of "r" and is evaluated at some range to see where the one_elect values become constant. However, this one_elect function is a function of different parameters too, such as different values of "a". In other words, the function, mathematically, should be represented as follows:

@MartinBrown In other words, the function, mathematically, should be represented as follows:  h_ij = {<a_i|h_ii|a_i>, <a_i|h_ij|a_j>, <a_j|h_ji|a_i>, <a_j|h_jj|a_j>}. I am very new to numerical methods, and I have yet to see Simpson's method, as I thought I should start with a more primitive approach and then build on it. I hope that clarified any misconceptions and I am sorry for any confusion being made on my part. It is hard to explain this stuff in texts due to some math jargon being used. -Moe
